# Invalid BigNumber Value Uniswap and Ethers JS

Tags: ropsten, uniswap, ethers.js

Hey guys I am using the Uniswap Javascript SDK and Ethers JS to make a swap but I am getting this

```
Error: invalid BigNumber value (argument="value", value=[-626648004,3158], code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.1.1)
```

This is my code:

```
            await window.ethereum.enable();
            let provider = new ethers.getDefaultProvider('ropsten');
            const signer =  (new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)).getSigner();
            console.log(provider.network.name);

            const amountIn = '1000000000000000000'; // 1 WETH

            const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
          
            const DENT = new Token(ChainId.ROPSTEN, "0xa51f5e00b3a454ba56c4add590d5cfeb2d197ae0", 8);
            const pair = await Fetcher.fetchPairData(DENT, WETH[DENT.chainId]);

            const route = new Route([pair], WETH[DENT.chainId]);
            console.log(route.midPrice.toSignificant(8));

            const trade = new Trade(route,  new TokenAmount(WETH[DENT.chainId], amountIn),  TradeType.EXACT_INPUT);

            const slippageTolerance = new Percent('50', '10000');  // 50 bips, or 0.50%

            const amountOutMin = trade.minimumAmountOut(slippageTolerance).raw; // needs to be converted to e.g. hex
            const path = [WETH[DENT.chainId].address, DENT.address];
            const to =  accounts[0]; // should be a checksummed recipient address

            const deadline = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 20; // 20 minutes from the current Unix time
            const value = trade.inputAmount.raw;  // // needs to be converted to e.g. hex

            const account = signer.connectUnchecked(provider);
       

            const uniswap = new ethers.Contract('0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D',['function swapExactETHForTokens(uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline) external payable returns (uint[] memory amounts)'], account);
            const tx = await uniswap.swapExactETHForTokens(amountOutMin, path, to, deadline, {value: value, gasPrice: 20e9});
```

I tried using the  ether's BigNumber constructor but I still got the same error. Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and it took me quite a while to find the root cause of this as the errors' messages were not super helpful.

Simply convert the `amountOutMin` and `value` values to `String` like this:

```
const tx = await uniswap.swapExactETHForTokens(
      String(amountOutMin),
      path,
      to,
      deadline,
      { value: String(value), gasPrice: 20e9 }
    );
```

It should work like a charm now (:

Answer (score 0):

the error you're getting is because somewhere in your code `[-626648004,3158]` value is being passed.

Can you tell which line is giving that error or provide the stack trace? That information can help us help you :)

Also, if you found the line which gives error, can you `console.log` in your JS code the variable inputs involved in that line, one of them should be `[-626648004,3158]`.